# I get errors when I deploy my app on AWS Lambda

Tags: python, flask, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, serverless

I am trying to run my flask api on AWS lambda, using `serverless framework` for deployment.

My app works fine locally when I use `sls wsgi serve` but I get errors (`502 bad gateway`) when I deploy to AWS Lambda :

```
021-03-12T16:26:21.213+01:00    START RequestId: deedf3d6-eb1e-4f02-ac0c-47428c5bd553 Version: $LATEST

2021-03-12T16:26:21.216+01:00   module initialization error: Unable to import app.app

2021-03-12T16:26:21.331+01:00   END RequestId: deedf3b6-eb1e-4f02-ac0c-47428c5bd553

2021-03-12T16:26:21.331+01:00   REPORT RequestId: deedf3b6-eb1e-4f02-ac0c-47428c5bd553 Duration: 115.30 ms Billed Duration: 116 ms Memory Size: 1024 MB Max Memory Used: 28 MB

2021-03-12T16:26:21.331+01:00   module initialization error Unable to import app.app

2021-03-12T16:26:22.072+01:00   Traceback (most recent call last):

2021-03-12T16:26:22.072+01:00   File "/var/task/wsgi_handler.py", line 44, in import_app

2021-03-12T16:26:22.072+01:00   wsgi_module = importlib.import_module(wsgi_fqn_parts[-1])

2021-03-12T16:26:22.072+01:00   File "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module

2021-03-12T16:26:22.072+01:00   return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)

2021-03-12T16:26:22.072+01:00   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import

2021-03-12T16:26:22.072+01:00

Copy
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load

2021-03-12T16:26:22.072+01:00   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked

2021-03-12T16:26:22.072+01:00   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked

2021-03-12T16:26:22.072+01:00   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module

2021-03-12T16:26:22.072+01:00   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed

2021-03-12T16:26:22.072+01:00   File "/var/task/app.py", line 10, in <module>

2021-03-12T16:26:22.072+01:00   from common.helpers import *

2021-03-12T16:26:22.072+01:00   File "/var/task/common/helpers.py", line 1, in <module>

2021-03-12T16:26:22.072+01:00   from common.db import db

2021-03-12T16:26:22.072+01:00   File "/var/task/common/db.py", line 1, in <module>

2021-03-12T16:26:22.072+01:00   from flask_pymongo import pymongo

2021-03-12T16:26:22.072+01:00   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_pymongo'
```

I have two separated files `app.py` and `db.py` in which the `Flask_pymongo` is imported.

This is my `DockerFile`

```
FROM lambci/lambda:build-python3.6
RUN pip3 --no-cache-dir install -r requirements.txt
```

`requirements.txt` :

```
Werkzeug==0.16.1
Flask_PyMongo==2.3.0
Flask==1.1.1
Flask_Limiter==1.3.1
Flask_JWT_Extended==3.22.0
pymongo==3.10.1
pymongo[tls,srv]
dnspython
```

And my `serverless.yml`

```
service : my-flask-app
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.6
  stage: dev
  region: us-east-1
plugins:
  - serverless-wsgi
  - serverless-python-requirements
custom:
  wsgi:
    app: app.app
    packRequirements: false
    pythonBin: python3
  pythonRequirements:
    dockerizePip: non-linux
    dockerFile: ./Dockerfile
package:
  exclude:
    - node_modules/**
    - venv/**
functions:
  app:
    handler: wsgi_handler.handler
    events:
      - http: ANY /
      - http: 'ANY {proxy+}'
```

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

I think your `Dockerfile` isn't correct, you are not copying `requirements.txt` to let pip install the packages for you because of this the dependencies are not packaged.  It should be something like this

```
FROM lambci/lambda:build-python3.6
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip3 --no-cache-dir install -r requirements.txt
```

Your `Dockerfile` gives this error :

```sh
Step 2/2 : RUN pip3 --no-cache-dir install -r requirements.txt
 ---> Running in 1cda237064f0
ERROR: Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'requirements.txt'
```

I am not sure if you noticed this in your build logs while deploying your app.

One more thing, you are not supposed to include the `requirements.txt` directly in your `Dockerfile` assuming you are using [serverless-python-requirements](https://github.com/UnitedIncome/serverless-python-requirements) not any other variant.

```yaml
  pythonRequirements:
    dockerizePip: non-linux
    dockerFile: ./Dockerfile
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM lambci/lambda:build-python3.6
# Install your dependencies in case you want to install any
#RUN yum -y install myfavourite-pacakge
```

This configuration will take the `Dockerfile` and add the `requirements.txt` to it.

[Native Code Dependencies During Build](https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-python-requirements)

[Cross Compiling](https://github.com/UnitedIncome/serverless-python-requirements#cross-compiling)